# Routing in codeigniter incorrect

Tags: codeigniter

This is the application structure

```
-app
 -controllers
  -v1
   -home.php
   -login.php  
 -models
  -v1
   -home_model.php
   -login_model.php 
 -views
  -v1
   -home
    -index.php
   -login
    -index.php
```

My default controller is `v1/home.php`

I want to remove v1 from the url while routing meaning the url should read www.abc.com/login instead of www.abc.com/v1/login

So when i release a v2 version of the app i can write another rule in the routes and v1 and v2 code both will be live at the same time.

here is what I have tried

```
$route['default_controller'] = "v1/home";
$route['v1/(:any)'] = "/$1";
```

Answer (score 0):

try these routes instead

```
$route['default_controller'] = "v1/home";
$route['(:any)'] = "v1/$1";
```

in future when v2 is ready, simply change it to

```
$route['(:any)'] = "v2/$1";
```

Comment: what if i want to keep v1 and v2 both live at the same time @jamesgiang

Comment: when v2 is ready and you want to also access v1 with `v1` in the URL then have `$route['v1/(:any)'] = "v1/$1";` above `$route['(:any)'] = "v2/$1";` in your route file

Comment: @jamesgiang this works except the url goes like www.abc.com/v1/home/get_users is there a way to remove the v1 from the url and in case of v2 the url contains www.abc.com/v2/home/get_users... is there a way to not have v1 or v2 in the url ?

Answer (score 0):

Hello Codeigniter support two types of routing rules

1)Wildcards

2)Regular Expressions

I prefer Wildcards

in routes just place this one

```
$route['login/(:any)'] = "v1/login";
```

A URL with "login" as the first segment, and anything in the second will be remapped to the "v1" class and the "login" method.

means your change www.abc.com/login instead of www.abc.com/v1/login

check it once routing in codeigniter here https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html
.......